# Can't collect pagination

Tags: ruby, parsing, nokogiri, curb

```
while page <= last_page

  pagination=("https://www.petsonic.com/snacks-huesos-para-perros/?=#{page}")
  puts pagination
  doc2=Nokogiri::HTML(Curl.get(pagination).body_str)

  links=doc2.xpath('//a[@class="product-name"]/@href')
  links.each do |url|
    doc3=Nokogiri::HTML(Curl.get(url).body_str)
    name1=doc3.xpath('//h1[@class="product_main_name"]').text
    puts name1
  end
  page +=1
end
```

However,for some reason it collects information from first page 4 times, instead of collection from all 4 pages. 
What might be the issue?

EDIT: i missed 'p' in `pagination=("https://www.petsonic.com/snacks-huesos-para-perros/?p=#{page}")`

Case closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a simple typo. Just replace

```
pagination=("https://www.petsonic.com/snacks-huesos-para-perros/?=#{page}")
```

with

```
pagination=("https://www.petsonic.com/snacks-huesos-para-perros/?p=#{page}")
```

Note the `p` in the query params.

Comment: oh jeez,my bad. Thanks